# Deixar marcado campos checkbox

Tags: php

Colegas. Gostaria que ao dar um post, os campos do checkbox ficassem selecionados conforme o usuário selecionou. Fiz da forma abaixo, mas ele só deixa marcado um campo:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="seg" name="DiaSemana" value="segunda-feira" <?php if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "DiaSemana") == "segunda-feira"){ echo "checked"; } ?>> Seg
<input type="checkbox" id="ter" name="DiaSemana" value="terça-feira" <?php if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "DiaSemana") == "terça-feira"){ echo "checked"; } ?>> Ter
<input type="checkbox" id="qua" name="DiaSemana" value="quarta-feira" <?php if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "DiaSemana") == "quarta-feira") echo "checked"; ?>> Qua
<input type="checkbox" id="qui" name="DiaSemana" value="quinta-feira" <?php if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "DiaSemana") == "quinta-feira") echo "checked"; ?>> Qui
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu não sei como é o sistema que está fazendo, então, supondo que seja apenas um form para marcar a checkbox, eu faria isso:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="seg" name="DiaSemana" value="segunda-feira" <?php if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "DiaSemana") == "segunda-feira"){ echo "checked"; } ?>> Seg
<input type="checkbox" id="ter" name="DiaSemana2" value="terça-feira" <?php if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "DiaSemana2") == "terça-feira"){ echo "checked"; } ?>> Ter
<input type="checkbox" id="qua" name="DiaSemana3" value="quarta-feira" <?php if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "DiaSemana3") == "quarta-feira") echo "checked"; ?>> Qua
<input type="checkbox" id="qui" name="DiaSemana4" value="quinta-feira" <?php if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "DiaSemana4") == "quinta-feira") echo "checked"; ?>> Qui
```